# Elasticsearch nested type select query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field with mapping:

```
   "my_field_name": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "labels": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "source": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
```

and when I put data, format is like:

```
"my_field_name": {
            "url_of_an_image": [
              "tag1",
              "tag2",
              "tag3",
              "tag4",
              "tag5"
            ],
            "url_of_an_image2": [
              "tag4",
              "tag5",
              "tag6",
              "tag7",
              "tag8"
            ]
}
```

I want to write an elasticsearch query to gather all the documents that contains given tag.

How can I search a tag in all documents and select the ones that contains given tag?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**EDITED AFTER COMMENT**)

As a first consideration, the mapping doesn't match the structure of your document, e.g., `my_field_name` has neither `labels` nor `source` fields. Which is the one that better represents your data?

As a second consideration, in your comment you said that

> while querying I don't know "url_of_an_image" since it is different for each document

However, from your example, it looks like `url_of_an_image` is a property of the items of `my_field_name` rather than of the document. Therefore, I'd suggest doing something like:

```
"my_field_name": [
  {
    "image_url": "url_of_an_image",
    "tags": [
       "tag1",
       "tag2",
       "tag3",
       "tag4",
       "tag5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "image_url": "url_of_an_image2",
    "tags": [
       "tag4",
       "tag5",
       "tag6",
       "tag7",
       "tag8"
    ]
  }
]
```

And this would be the mapping:

```
"my_field_name": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
     "image_url": {
       "type": "text"
     },
     "tags": {
       "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can run queries like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested" : {
      "path" : "my_field_name",
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            { "match" : {"my_field_name.image_url" : "url_of_an_image2"} },
            { "match" : {"my_field_name.tags" : "tag3"} }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @glenacota, unfortunately it did not worked. And moreover, while querying I don't know "url_of_an_image" since it is different for each document (some of documents may have the same url_of_an_image but it is not important). I am trying to find a way to query without specifying a "url_of_an_image". I have different documents with different "url_of_an_image"s and each of them has a list of tags. I want to gather all the documents that contain given tag

Comment: Hello @glenacota, I will update here after trying your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the Nested Query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: Actually, it does not provide me a solution. I tried it already